# Nav Walker current menu item not displaying

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm building a theme on top of a starter theme (wp-bootstrap) and am having trouble getting the Nav Walker to show the current menu item. current-menu-item is not there when I use a web inspector on the output html. So therefore I can't style it.

This is the code in my template file:

```
          <?php
       /** Loading WordPress Custom Menu  **/
       wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu'            => 'main-menu',
          'container' => '',
          'container_class' => 'navbar-blue',
          'menu_class'      => 'nav',
          'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
          'walker' => new Bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
      ) ); ?>
```

And this is the code in function.php:

```
include 'includes/class-bootstrapwp_walker_nav_menu.php';
```

And finally this is the code from the customer nav walker file:

```
class Bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function __construct() {
}
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {

$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
  }
}
```

I've looked over a few stackexchange answers and tried changing the code to match them, but nothing has solved the issue (ie: nothing has made current-menu-item appear in the html output).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and you get `current-menu-item` when you skip the walker?

Comment: I've deleted the walker line in the array and still no `current-menu-item`. I've also tried replacing the whole array block with the default version from the wp codex and no joy.

Comment: Okay, I've discovered that if I place the wp-nav-menu array in _header.php_, I get `current-menu-item` to display but my site design has the same menu code in _sidebar.php_ and it doesn't work - any suggestions on how to fix this? _header.php_ was the original position for the menu in the starter theme framework.

Comment: maybe you need to reset the global `$post` value again? you could try `<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>` before the sidebar part.

Comment: Sadly no, that didn't work. Thank you for help on this by the way.

Comment: what about placing `$nav=wp_nav_menu(...)` in the `header.php` file with the `'echo'=>0` option and then `echo $nav;` in the sidebar?

Comment: Can you give me a bit more detail on that please? I've dropped `'echo' => '0'` in the top version which hides it. For the 2nd instance of the nav, do I have the same, full code with `'echo' => '$nav'`? or just `<?php echo $nav; ?>`? Or something else? I've tried those 2 things and neither solved it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is working as you expect in the `header.php` file (but not in `sidebar.php`),
you could add this into `header.php`:

```
global $my_nav;
$my_nav= wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu'            => 'main-menu',
          'container' => '',
          'container_class' => 'navbar-blue',
          'menu_class'      => 'nav',
          'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
          'walker' => new Bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
          'echo' => 0,
      ) ); ?>
```

and then in your `sidebar.php` file you could add

```
global $my_nav;
echo $my_nav;
```

to display the menu.